# Ask and answering your own question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a whole bunch of questions that I asked when I first started using vim. So I have an answer for them now. So I can keep asking and answering my own questions like:

- [How do I use vim as a diff tool](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/625/383)
- [vimdiff and merge conflicts](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/660/383)

But is there some guidelines on doing this.

Comment: In general: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136617/when-should-i-post-a-question-with-the-answer?lq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to?rq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

Answering your own question is encouraged.  However, please be fair about accepting your own answer, if at all.  I would consider the following etiquette rules to be reasonable:

- Be sure to upvote competing answers generously, if they are any good at all.
- Wait several days before even considering accepting your own answer.
- If your answer didn't get a reasonable number of upvotes during that time, then it's probably not good enough to accept.
- Accept your own answer only if it is significantly better than all other answers.

Comment: That's good advice for answering them. But I am more looking for advice/guidelines about they type of question I can ask in this manner. I don't want to be seen like I am trying to game the system for rep.

Comment: To be clear, I listed those rules as public guidelines, in no way implying that you violated any of them. I think your selfies so far are fine.

Comment: FYI: You can't accept your own answer immediately, the site does not let you (at least, on other SE sites, I haven't tested here).

Answer (score 5):

[It is allowed, even encouraged, to answer one's own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/172958)—that's why you have a checkbox when asking a question

> Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

That said, many people on the network are quite... picky when a user answers their own question. Just make sure your question and answer are both high quality and you should be fine, though you may still get an occasional downvote from users who disagree with the network's self-answer policy.